# Subversion Branch in Mode-Line

Tags: git, svn, emacs, version-control, modeline

If a file lies in a directory backed by a Subversion repo ending with either `trunk` or `branches/X` how do I make the `trunk` or `X` show up in the mode-line as `SVN-trunk` or `SVN-X` similar to what is shown in Git-backed files typically as `Git-master`.

Comment: I don't get the downvote either. +1'ing to fix this.

Comment: Another upvote to set things right.  This is a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Determining SVN status

I am not aware of any built-in way to do this, but you can write your own code for this purpose.

Based on `vc-svn-repository-name` and `vc-backend` you can write a function that returns a custom mode text for SVN, and falls back to the default for all other VC systems:

```
(defun lunaryorn-vc-mode-line ()
  (let ((backend (vc-backend (buffer-file-name))))
    (if (eq backend 'SVN)
        (let ((url (vc-svn-repository-hostname (buffer-file-name))))
          (cond
           ((string-match-p "/trunk/" url) "SVN-trunk")
           ((string-match "/branches/\\([^/]+\\)/" url)
            (concat "SVN-" (match-string 1 url)))
           (t vc-mode)))
      ;; Use default mode text for other backends
      vc-mode)))
```

If the current file is under SVN, we check its repo URL according to your convention and compile a corresponding mode text.  Don't be confused by the name of `vc-svn-repository-hostname`, the function actually returns the complete repo URL of the given file.

For all other backends, or if the URL does not match any pattern, we fall back to the default VC status text as in `vc-mode`.

## Adding to the mode line

You can then use this function in the mode line, by adding a corresponding mode line construct to `mode-line-format`:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
              '(…
                (vc-mode (" " (:eval (lunaryorn-vc-mode-line))))
                …))
```

Since `mode-line-format` is buffer-local, we use `setq-default` to change its global value.  Our new mode line construct checks whether `vc-mode` is active, that is, whether the file is under version control, and evaluates our function in this case, to obtain our custom status text.  See [Mode Line Data](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data) for more information about mode line constructs.

The ellipsis stand for the other content of the mode line, which you may also customize to your liking.  I'd suggest, though, that you simply copy the default value of `mode-line-format`, and replace `(vc-mode vc-mode)` with our new construct.  That will simply replace the old VC information with our custom status text, and leaves everything else as before.

Comment: Superb answer! Only one thing: Can I programmatically replace `(vc-mode vc-mode)` with `(vc-mode (" " :eval (lunaryorn-vc-mode-line)))` in `mode-line-format`? I don't want to hard-code my mode-line format in this package `svn-mode-line`. IMHO that's too intrusive.

Comment: I get the feeling that this could be made more elegant. Shouldn't the definition of `vc-mode-line` or some of its sub-logic be overridden somehow? Hmm, it seems as if the defintion of `vc-mode-line` lacks a bit of flexibility that could be implemented using by hooks or function variables.

Comment: @Nordlöw If you'd like to put this in a proper package and distribute it, you should not touch `mode-line-format` at all.  Packages shouldn't mess with user customization.  Instead, just instruct users how to setup your package.

Comment: @Nordlöw Well, you could also define the `vc-svn-mode-line-string` function like Stefan suggested.  VC Mode will call this function to get a mode line string for SVN.  That's probably also more efficient than re-evaluating VC state on every mode line update.

Comment: Great! I'll try that later on. Thx.

Comment: Is there an Emacs function to modify only `(vc-mode vc-mode)` part in `mode-line-format` typically to `(vc-mode (" " :eval (lunaryorn-vc-mode-line)))`? I know I can extra it with `(assoc 'vc-mode mode-line-format)`.

Comment: @Nordlöw `(setcdr (assq 'vc-mode mode-line-format) (whatever-you-want)`.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I do `(setcdr (assq 'vc-mode mode-line-format) '(vc-fancy-mode-line-string))` the vc information in mode-line disappears in all buffers. So far I have https://github.com/nordlow/elisp/blob/master/mine/svn-mode-line.el

Comment: @Nordlöw `'(vc-fancy-mode-line-string)` is an invalid mode line construct.  You'll need `'(:eval (vc-fancy-mode-line-string))`.  Please read [Mode Line Data](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data).

Comment: @Nordlöw By the way, I saw that you defined `vc-svn-mode-line-string`.  You don't need to change `vc-mode` anymore then. VC automatically calls that function to get status text for SVN.

Comment: My definition of `vc-svn-mode-line-string` is not run. I dont' know why. This when I have `vc-mode` set to `vc-mode` in `mode-line-format`.

Comment: Ok, now it works with using eval at https://github.com/nordlow/elisp/blob/master/mine/svn-mode-line.el. Thanks. Added some coloring of the SVN version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59616/discussion-between-nordlow-and-lunaryorn).

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function:

```
(defun vc-svn-mode-line-string (file)
  (format "SVN-%s" (vc-svn-current-branch-name file)))
```

Of course, you'd also have to define `vc-svn-current-branch-name` because that one doesn't exist yet.  I guess it would have to do something like

```
(defun vc-svn-current-branch-name (file)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (setq default-directory (file-name-directory file))
    (vc-svn-command t t file "info")
    ...extract the branch name from the info in current buffer..
    ))
```

Comment: Defining function `vc-svn-mode-line-string` has no effect in my Emacs (git master).

Comment: There's some caching going on, so make sure you define it before you load vc-svn.el (e.g. put it in your .emacs and then restart).  Try `(defun vc-svn-mode-line-string (file) "TEST")` for a start.